# hadoop sqoop load csv file into mysql

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am learning hadoop sqoop. I am working on a hortonworks sandbox (a hadoop virtual machine of single node: http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install).

I am trying to load a csv file via sqoop into a mysql table. I have created a database flightinfo and a table weather in it. I created a table in hive called sqoop_tmp with the file location of that csv file.

I used following command to load the csv into mysql:

```
    sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/flightinfo –-table weather –-export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sqoop_tmp
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

update: @z-1 
I tried your code and it returns something different
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide username and password of MySQL and must have permissions to access the database.

It looks like you did a fresh install of mysql and didn't not configure the root account to secure with root password.

You can do that using the following steps:

1. `$ mysqladmin -u root password "newpassword"`
   for example `$ mysqladmin -u root password mysql-root-password`
2. Restart MySQL daemon. `$ sudo service mysqld restart` or `$ sudo /etcinit.d/mysqld restart`
3. Login to MySQL using `$ mysql -u root -P` and enter the password when prompted.

If you have your database created as root user. Now you can issue the following sqoop command to export data from hdfs to sqoop database.

`$ sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/flightinfo --username root -P --table weather --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sqoop_tmp`

Still facing permission issue?? Permission to the user to access database is the problem.

Then, You should be able to solve by granting permissions using the steps below.

1. Login to MySQL using `$ mysql -u root -P`
2. `mysql> GRANT all PRIVILEGES on filghtinfo.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

   Note: The password you set here should be used from sqoop.

Comment: In 1) I tried $ mysqladmin -u root password "newpassword" and $ mysqladmin -u root password mysql-root-password under mysql shell, it says error in sql syntax.

Comment: I think if the password is already set. The above command is not allowed. Instead try `$mysql_secure_installation` to reset the password if you are not sure of what password for root.

Comment: I didn't do 1) 2)3), just run the sqoop statement with username root, it then prompts for password, I googled and someone says for mysql it should be root or empty, I tried empty, and it works!

Comment: Thats awesome. The above commands shows how to set a root password and use that root password against this sqoop. And I just missed that the default is empty and using that it sqoop.

Comment: You got it finally. Super.. :)

Answer (score 1):

try with username and password of mysql

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/flightinfo --table weather --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sqoop_tmp --username SomeUser -P
```

Note - user should have permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/flightinfo --table weather --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/sqoop_tmp
```

You had `–-` not `--`. These two are not the same.

Comment: I added a screen shot. Your suggestion is correct but there is another error (see the screen shot). Thanks.

Comment: It looks like authentication problem to the mysql server. How do I find the username and password? I can just type mysql under hadoop shell to enter mysql shell, it never asked for username or password.

Comment: see @Avinash's answer. You need to provide a username and password